# How can I create a list of currently logged in users in Play Framework 2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I would like to be able to create a list of all currently logged in users with an active session.

I know this goes against Play Framework's stateless philosophy...

This might not be easily possible, so the MINIMUM I need is to find a way to prevent a user from logging in from a different IP at the same time (i.e. prevent the second login).  This means I need to keep a list of which user is logged into from which IP in such a way that it expires when the session expires.

I would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without adding further dependencies by creating an actor per active user in a distributed Akka system.

1. Actor is created when user first logs in.  Use the unique identifier of the user as the actor name.  The actor keeps the IP address the user logs in from.
2. At log in, check if an actor for the user already exists.  If it doesn't, allow log in.  If it does, check the IP address against that of the current log-in request.
3. Each actor should schedule a poison pill to itself, to be sent x minutes in the future.  The actor should keep a reference to the scheduling event
4. In your DeadboltHandler#getSubject implementation, send a message to the current user's actor to cancel the poison pill, and reschedule another one x minutes in the future.

If you're using the session timeout mechanism you blogged about (http://www.poornerd.com/2014/04/01/how-to-implement-a-session-timeout-in-play-framework-2/) I guess you would set x to be the same timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

There is not generic way of doing so. Play is full stack framework providing you tools to do the way you want. As for any web framework there as many authentication way as you want, as many way to track logged users: storing in DB, using STM in an object/singleton, in Redis, Mongo, ...

Choice is mainly up to you.